# Python List of Lists

Tags: python

I am stuck at one point where I want to create a list of lists something like

```
[ [3,2,5], [4,8,1]...]
```

I have written the following code but it prints [3,2,5,4,8,1,....] and not the way I want the structure to be. Any help would be appreciated.

```
skill=[]
db=[ [] ]
file=open(filePath,'r')
for line in file:
    for word in line.split(','):
        skill.append(itDictionary[word.strip()])
    db.append(skill)
print db
```

Comment: What do the lines in file look like?

Comment: lines in files are simply comma separated strings having values in dictionary, I am storing those values like in my example above.

Comment: itDictionary[word.strip()] will return a value (numeric) that I am storing in list.

Comment: So each line only has one set of comma delimited numbers?  Because if that is the case, your code looks like it should work.  Could you actually paste in an example of the file and itDictionary?

Comment: you might want to look at using `with open(filePath) as infp:` instead of using `open` by itself as this will close the file for you when you are done with it. Looks also like list comprehension might be useful here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would do:

```
db=[]
file=open(filePath,'r')
for line in file:
    skill = []
    for word in line.split(','):
        skill.append(itDictionary[word.strip()])
    db.append(skill)
print db
```

Comment: Ha Ha. Perfect :) Thanks a lot! Even I got what was the mistake I was making.

Comment: always happy to lend a hand with the python lists

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell what you really need, but why don't you try something like:

```
db = []
with open(filePath, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        db.append([itDictionary[word.strip()] for word in line.split(',')])
print db
```